# How to make sure two VF pages using the same controller dont share data

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have 2 VF page which use the same controller extension and i am calling the second page from the first page.

The data used on the controller is persisted upon when the second page is loaded and url remains the same and is not moved to the second page. Is there a way i change the url to the second page?

The issue that i have with persisting data is that when i click the save in the first page it updates the record and based on the update a formula is also changed accordingly. When i go to the second page it still uses the value of the formula value which was loaded in the first page.

A good explanation to what is happening is mentioned here 
http://writeforce.blogspot.in/2014/08/demystifying-pagereference.html

> So, the rule is if the page to which the redirect happens shares the same controller as the page that did the redirect, then Salesforce will do a server-side redirect. In all other cases, a client-side redirect is done by sending the redirection javascript in the response.

Is there a way i make sure that the data is not persisted upon from the first page and the url is changed to the second page.

```
public pageReference goToSaveDecline()
    {
        try
        {
        this.acct.Onboarding_Status__c = 'Overview Email';
        update this.acct;
        PageReference pr =new pagereference('/apex/offeringAcceptDecline?id='+this.acct.id);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
        }
        catch(exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getmessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This code is run when a button is clicked from first page

Comment: are you using .setRedirect(true);

Comment: so, when you go to next page get the refreshed data and assign it to relevant variables. URL may be changed by `setRedirect(true)` but never tried it.

Comment: setRedirect will change url

Comment: SetRedirect(true) doesnt change url if the pages are sharing same controller

Comment: @Himanshu i want to get the value of the formula field in the constructor and  constructor itself doesnt run

Comment: Please share your markup, as without that it is very difficult to assess.

Comment: @Prady setRedirect(true) will definitely change the url, please share your markup code

Comment: It's a lot less verbose to just do `ApexPages.addMessages(e)`. Are you sure you're not entering your `catch` block?